# Reading large files in Scala

Tags: java, scala, io

I am using `io.Source.fromFile` and `getLines` to read a text file. I find that the `size` method of `Iterator` returns an `Int`, which means that the file should not contain more than 2^31 lines. I know that I can solve this problem by resorting to `java.io.Scanner`. However, is there a Scala way to work around this?

Comment: If you have a file that big, you should look into streaming solutions like: **fs2**, **Monix** _(observables)_, **AkkaStreams**, **Zio** _(ZStream)_, etc.

Comment: As the lines internally probably are held in an array of max 2^31 entries, would you not rather need to use an import to a database?

Comment: If you just want to iterate over all the lines you can probably still use an `Iterator` as long you don't call methods like `size` or convert to a collection or array.

Answer (score 0):

or you could roll your own iterator on top of a mapped file, courtesy of java's file mapping interface?  https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2955144&seqNum=5